# Is it save for me to dispatch multiple actions on a single useEffect hook in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a list of actions i want to call when my page loads, is it save to dispatch all those actions like so:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(action1())
    dispatch(action2())
    dispatch(action3())
    dispatch(action4())
  }, [])
```